# google buzz api error

Tags: database, api, storage, google-buzz

I am trying to post some content to my google buzz account using google buzz api.
I tried using their sample code that they have provided ,but it give the below error

```
Array
```

(
    [http_code] => 401
    [headers] => Array
        (
            [WWW-Authenticate] => AuthSub realm="https://www.google.com/accounts/AuthSubRequest" allowed-scopes="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/buzz"
            [Content-Type] => application/json; charset=UTF-8
            [Date] => Tue, 20 Jul 2010 12:22:05 GMT
            [Expires] => Tue, 20 Jul 2010 12:22:05 GMT
            [Cache-Control] => private, max-age=0
            [X-Content-Type-Options] => nosniff
            [X-Frame-Options] => SAMEORIGIN
            [X-XSS-Protection] => 1; mode=block
            [Server] => GSE
            [Transfer-Encoding] => chunked
        )

```
[data] => Array
    (
        [error] => Array
            (
                [errors] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [message] => User must have authorized this application to have the following scope in order to make this call: [https://www.googleapis.com/auth/buzz]  Also , make sure your application is using the Buzz specific OAuth authorization URL.
                                [locationType] => header
                                [location] => Authorization
                            )

                    )

                [code] => 401
                [message] => User must have authorized this application to have the following scope in order to make this call: [https://www.googleapis.com/auth/buzz]  Also , make sure your application is using the Buzz specific OAuth authorization URL.
            )

    )
```

)

i have added the variables in the config.php file which were required

```
'site_name' => 'example.com',
```

'oauth_consumer_key' => 'example.com',
  'oauth_consumer_secret' => 'consumersecret',
  'oauth_rsa_key' => '',

Does anybody know what i might be doing wrong here??

How can i store the tokens that are returned to the database?? Since if the server is restarted the cache is lost and the users have to authenticate again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was with the domain that i was passing. Instead of passing example.com i was passing http://example.com . So make sure the site_name , oauth_consumer_key and domain variables are passed properly.

Comment: `site_name` and `oauth_consumer_key` should always be the same value.